# Generic function for all number-like values?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'd like to write a generic Kotlin function that works with arbitrary types, as long as they support some basic numeric operations, such as comparison and addition. Something like this (note: this code doesn't compile):

```kotlin
fun <T : ???> twiceTheLarger(a: T, b: T) = if (a > b) a + a else b + b;
```

In C++, this kind of code works. The following C++ `twiceTheLarger` function takes anything that supports the `+` and `>` operators, be it a primitive numeric type or a custom class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> T twiceTheLarger(T a, T b) {
  return a > b ? a + a : b + b;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << twiceTheLarger(1, 2) << std::endl; // int values
  std::cout << twiceTheLarger(42.0, 1.0) << std::endl; // double values
}
```

How can I get a similar result in Kotlin? The best way I could come up so far is to explicitly pass an object with the required functions, like this:

```kotlin
interface NumericOperators<T> {
    fun plus(a: T, b: T): T
    fun greaterThan(a: T, b: T): Boolean
}

object IntNumericOperators : NumericOperators<Int> {
    override fun plus(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
    override fun greaterThan(a: Int, b: Int) = a > b
}

object DoubleNumericOperators : NumericOperators<Double> {
    override fun plus(a: Double, b: Double) = a + b
    override fun greaterThan(a: Double, b: Double) = a > b
}

fun <T> twiceTheLarger(a: T, b: T, operators: NumericOperators<T>) =
    if (operators.greaterThan(a, b)) operators.plus(a, a) else operators.plus(b, b)

fun main() {
    println(twiceTheLarger(1, 2, IntNumericOperators)) // int values
    println(twiceTheLarger(42.0, 1.0, DoubleNumericOperators)) // double values
}
```

Is there a better way?

**Edit:**

I realize that I could create overloads for each primitive numeric type. The thing is that I'm writing a library function that needs to work with *arbitrary* number-like types, even types my library doesn't know about. So type-specific overloads are not an option.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create functions for each primitive type. You can't use `<T : Number>`, despite all numbers in Kotlin inherit this. `Number` superclass is used only for the castings.

You'll need to create functions or extension functions:

`fun Int.twiceTheLarger(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a + a else b + b;`

`fun Double.twiceTheLarger(a: Double, b: Double) = if (a > b) a + a else b + b;`

It would be great if you can utilize `Comparable<T>` in another function for the comparison. Types of `T` need to overload `operator fun plus(other: T)` as well.

```kotlin
    interface Addable<T>: Comparable<T>{
       operator fun <T> Addable<T>.plus(a: T)
    }
    fun <T : Addable<T>> T.twiceTheLarger(a: T, b: T) {
        return if (a > b) a.plus(a) else b + b
    }
```

Comment: That would be a good approach if I knew the types in advance. I've added a paragraph to my question clarifying that this is not the case.

Comment: @DanielWolf See my edit and the comment about operator.

Comment: I'm afraid your function doesn't compile because the compiler can't ensure that every type implementing `Comparable<T>` also implements the plus operator.